# Toggle function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So at the beginning I know this code is messy. I have a `div` that I want to copy, when I click on the `div`, it opens up a Content and it copies that `div`. The thing I can't seem to accomplish is this, In that copied version of div/Image, I can close the content, but when I press on it again, I can't seem to open the component. If you don't fully understand it here is the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-lake-uovir?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `ref` in the first `div` so the `click` event can be checked with `handleProject`.

There are 2 functions run when you click the copied version.
`onClick` of the `div` triggers `setIsProjectOpen(true)`, then the `eventListenter` you added to `useEffect` triggers `setIsProjectOpen(false)`.
You can do this:

```
        <div
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            setIsProjectOpen(!isProjectOpen)}};
          className={
            "smallProjects__container " + (isProjectOpen ? "active" : "")
          }
        >
```